# Include number of missing values in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using `ggplot2` to plot different time series (one for Alice, one for Bob, one for Eve), which have a different number of missing values.

```
require('ggplot2')
df3 <-  data.frame(name=c(rep("Alice",10),rep("Bob",10),rep("Eve",10)),value=c(seq(1,10), seq(4,13), seq(5,14)), time=rep(seq(1,10),3))
df3$value[c(3,4,15,16,17,22,23,24,25)]<- NA
ggplot(data=df3, aes(time, value)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point() + facet_wrap(~ name, nrow=1)
```

I'd like to have the count of `NA`s displayed in each of the plots, e.g. as an overlay of a number (2 for Alice, 3 for Bob, 4 for Eve). Is there an elegant way to do this?

Comment: create a dataset with the number of NA for each name and then use geom_text() to add the values to the plot.

Comment: I asked a similar question and got help here.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25081619/combine-calculated-value-with-text-in-ggplot2-annotation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @MLavoie suggested in the comments, generate a new dataframe for the text labels then work with that. This should work for your purposes:

```
require('ggplot2')
require('dplyr')

df3 <-      data.frame(name=c(rep("Alice",10),rep("Bob",10),rep("Eve",10)),value=c(seq(1,10), seq(4,13), seq(5,14)), time=rep(seq(1,10),3))
df3$value[c(3,4,15,16,17,22,23,24,25)]<- NA

NAdf<-df3 %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarise(ycoor=mean(value, na.rm=TRUE),
            xcoor=mean(time, na.rm=TRUE),
            num_NA=sum(is.na(value)))  


ggplot(data=df3, aes(time, value)) + 
 geom_line() + 
 geom_point() + 
 geom_text(data=NAdf, aes(x=xcoor, y=ycoor, label=paste(num_NA,"for",name))) +
 facet_wrap(~ name, nrow=1)
```

[image]
HTH

### Updated

In response to the comment below. Generally I find placing text labels into a facetted plot fairly finicky. In your example you could simply define the x and y coordinates as 5,5 for all panels like this:

```
NAdf<-df3 %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarise(ycoor=5,
            xcoor=5,
            num_NA=sum(is.na(value)))
```

Then you could plot using the same code as before:

```
 ggplot(data=df3, aes(time, value)) + 
 geom_line() + 
 geom_point() + 
 geom_text(data=NAdf, aes(x=xcoor, y=ycoor, label=paste(num_NA,"for",name))) +
 facet_wrap(~ name, nrow=1)
```

The issue with this is that it isn't a generalized solution. In practice though I find you need to fiddle with your geom_text plotting coordinates each and every time to get it just right. Truth be told @Sam Dickson's solution is very elegant for this particular problem.

Comment: What's the `%>%`? I'm getting an error: `Error: could not find function "%>%"
`

Comment: You need to load `dplyr`. Also it is `%>%` not `%<%`. Think of `%>%` (called a pipe) as the word "then". It is automatic for me to use pipes these days.

Comment: What if the time series consists entirely of 'NAs'? Is the some way to place the text in the middle of each of the boxes?

Answer (score 2):

One option is to add the count to the variable used in the faceting:

```
df3$NAs <- ave(df$value,df$name,FUN=function(x) sum(is.na(x))))
df3$name1 <- paste0(df3$name,' (NA = ',df3$NAs,')') 
ggplot(data=df3, aes(time, value)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point() + facet_wrap(~ name1, nrow=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Your solution is very elegant and nice, but unfortunately, it doesn't work for `facet_grid`s, where I'd like to use this information as well.